# What does "in a complete froth about" mean?

Tags: phrase-meaning

**Source**: [*The Executive Guide to Artificial Intelligence: How to identify and implement applications for AI in your organization*](https://books.google.com.eg/books?id=avM-DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA13&lpg=PA13&dq=%22The+marketing+machines+and+industry+analysts+are+in+a+complete+froth%22&source=bl&ots=12EDkGOKVe&sig=PlwGYTFUKoa9RTXFaSIVoRTrbyU&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiS_vK44u_cAhWSaFAKHUVGBDAQ6AEwAHoECAAQAQ#v=onepage&q=%22The%20marketing%20machines%20and%20industry%20analysts%20are%20in%20a%20complete%20froth%22&f=false) by Andrew Burgess

> I talk about these AI Winters in a little detail because there is the obvious question of whether the current boom in AI is just another case of over-inflated expectations that will lead to a third spell of the technology being left out in the cold. As we have seen in the previous chapter, **the marketing machines and industry analysts are in a complete froth** about AI and what it will be capable of.

I consulted dictionaries and searched google for *in a froth about idiom*, but I couldn't find anything helpful. Thanks in advance.

Comment: The underlying comparison is to a rabid dog, frothing at the mouth.  It means more than "excited".  It means excited to the point  of madness.  It's a form of exaggeration.

Answer (score 7):

To be **in a froth** about something is to be worked up or agitated by it.

From the Collins definition of the verb [**froth**](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/froth):

> If you say that someone **is frothing**, or that they **are frothing** at the mouth, you are emphasizing that they are very angry or excited about something.
>
> [*written*, emphasis]
>   *'No! No! Never!' he froths.* [VERB with quote]
>   *This story has many ingredients which make any news editor froth at the mouth with excitement.* [VERB preposition]

Comment: So it means excited in the original sentence?

Comment: @Sara Most likely. At the very least, they are being kept busy producing marketing material and analyses. It's like disturbing an ants' nest. :)

Comment: +1; the OP's quote is indeed a variant of [_frothing at the mouth_](https://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/frothing+at+the+mouth), which is an established idiom.

Comment: "Foaming at the mouth" is, in my experience at least, a much more common idiom. I believe the source is from the archetype of enraged people losing control with spittle flying from their mouth as they fight/scream/shout. An alternate source I've read (and that I'm looking for) is related to dogs with rabies, where they typically produce excess foamy spittle and are known to be erratic & savage.  Frothing at the mouth & foaming at the mouth are interchangeable, but the latter is probably more contemporary/in everyday usage.